# Issue faced while accessing the session of CorePHP Applicaiton in Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have following two applications:

1. Application in CorePHP
2. Application in Laravel

I want to access the session from CorePHP application to the Laravel application.

For this, I used the following process:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\HttpFoundation\Response;


class UserAuthenticateMiddleware extends Middleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    foreach(Session::all() as $key => $value)
            {
                $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
            }
            print_r($_SESSION);
        }
}
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::addCookieToResponse() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given, called in /home/dixon/php7esupport/esupport/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php
```

What can be the possible reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are not showing your entire function you are forgetting `return $next($request);`

So it would be something like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    foreach(Session::all() as $key => $value){
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. I get the same error even with the idea you suggested.

Comment: What order did you define the middleware in App/Http/Kernel.php make sure it is defined after the StartSession middleware

Comment: I corrected that part and overcome that issue. But now I'm getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant 'Illuminate\View\Middleware\StartSession' in /home/dixon/php7esupport/esupport/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:800

Comment: Seems you have a syntax error. Either use `Illuminate\View\Middleware\StartSession::class` or `'Illuminate\View\Middleware\StartSession'`